# Using Master Page Method On child page gives error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

Below code I am using to use master page method but it is showing masterLogin is not a member of Online_Medicines_order_online_medcineHeader

```
TryCast(Me.Master, Online_Medicines_order_online_medcineHeader).masterLogin()
```

Method I want to call{masterLogin()} is below from master page

```
Partial Class Online_Medicines_order_online_medcineHeader
    Public Sub masterLogin()
         mp0.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Why this error keeps coming? Anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the page using this specific masterpage? Why is that partial class?

Comment: @Esko I also tried using public class instead of partial but still it shown the same error